# parsing decoded json into php loop

Tags: php, json, parsing

Hi can someone please help me, i have this decoded json string and i want to loop over it and get some data..

this is the decoded json:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'date' => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
          public 'day' => int 1
          public 'month' => int 1
          public 'year' => int 2014
          public 'dayOfWeek' => int 3
      public 'localName' => string 'New Year's Day' (length=14)
      public 'englishName' => string 'New Year's Day' (length=14)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'date' => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'day' => int 27
          public 'month' => int 1
          public 'year' => int 2014
          public 'dayOfWeek' => int 1
      public 'localName' => string 'Australia Day' (length=13)
      public 'englishName' => string 'Australia Day' (length=13)
      public 'note' => string 'Holiday in lieu of 26 Jan 2014' (length=30)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'date' => 
        object(stdClass)[6]
          public 'day' => int 18
          public 'month' => int 4
          public 'year' => int 2014
          public 'dayOfWeek' => int 5
      public 'localName' => string 'Good Friday' (length=11)
      public 'englishName' => string 'Good Friday' (length=11)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[7]
      public 'date' => 
        object(stdClass)[8]
          public 'day' => int 21
          public 'month' => int 4
          public 'year' => int 2014
          public 'dayOfWeek' => int 1
      public 'localName' => string 'Easter Monday' (length=13)
      public 'englishName' => string 'Easter Monday' (length=13)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[9]
      public 'date' => 
        object(stdClass)[10]
          public 'day' => int 25
          public 'month' => int 12
          public 'year' => int 2014
          public 'dayOfWeek' => int 4
      public 'localName' => string 'Christmas Day' (length=13)
      public 'englishName' => string 'Christmas Day' (length=13)
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)[11]
      public 'date' => 
        object(stdClass)[12]
          public 'day' => int 26
          public 'month' => int 12
          public 'year' => int 2014
          public 'dayOfWeek' => int 5
      public 'localName' => string 'Boxing Day' (length=10)
      public 'englishName' => string 'Boxing Day' (length=10)
```

I want to loop over it somehow and get the values, **date**, **englishName**,

this is my code:

```
foreach ($holidays as $eventobj)
{
    foreach ($eventobj as $event)
    {
        $date = $event[0] . "<BR />";
        $englishName = $event[2] . "<BR />";
    }
}
```

but this does not work, can someone show me how? Thanks!

Comment: Is that necessary to decode to standard class? try [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) with true

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with an array of objects, therefore...

```
foreach ($holidays as $event) {
    $englishName = $event->englishName; // kinda redundant

    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setDate($event->date->year, $event->date->month, $event->date->month);
    // and to set the time to 0
    $date->setTime(0, 0);
}
```